# No notifications on iPhone 4 running jailbroken iOS 6.1.2

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, notifications

I have recently been given an unlocked iPhone 4 GSM, upon which I have installed a jailbroken (but not hacktivated) iOS 6.1.2 using snowbreeze. Calling seems to work fine, as does everything except notifications. They appear to be turned on in the notification centre settings, but I never get any.  I am not using the Apple Mail app, but I have Gmail, Facebook, Twitter installed and connected.  Can anyone suggest how I might fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this was caused by restoring an iCloud backup from a previous install which had been hacktivated. Notifications will not work with a hacktivated iPhone, and it seems as though they won't work with a restored iCloud backup of a hacktivated iPhone either.

The solution is therefore to restore the jailbroken image and set it up as a new phone. This will then activate with Apple's servers and notifications will work.